# I'm Using Firebase Messaging in Flutter Android App But I getting Only System Tray Notification Not Background Notification. why?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Background Notification(With Flutter Local Notification) Working Properly In Android Emulatore but my Physical Devices Not Getting Background Notification.

**main.dart**

```
AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'id',
  'name',
  description: 'This channel is used for Importance notification.',
  importance: Importance.high,
  playSound: true,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
 FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background messageid: ${message.messageId}');
  Map<String, dynamic> objectdata3 = json.decode(message.data['data']);
  var title = objectdata3['title'];
  var body = objectdata3['body'];
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        title,
        body,
        NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              channelDescription: channel.description,
              color: Colors.orange,
              playSound: true,
              icon: '@mipmap/ic',

            )
        ),
        payload: 'data'
    );
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Give me a Reason why not i am Not Getting Background Notification On Physical Android Devices.

Comment: check out ur Apps "Notification permission" is on or not

Comment: @JBJason notification permission true . and Android emulatore is working properly (Background Notification).

Comment: foreground notification is working with onclick events. but System Tray Notification Onclick events not working.